# Doubly Linked List default typename Node

Tags: c++, list, templates, c++11

I'm writing a simple Doubly Linked List which looks like this:

Node.h

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    Node() : _next(nullptr), _prev(nullptr) {}
    Node(Node* next, Node* prev, T data) : _next(next), _prev(prev), _data(data) {}

    Node* Next() { return _next; }
    Node* Prev() { return _prev; }
    T  Source() { return _data; }

    Node* _next;
    Node* _prev;
    T   _data;
};
```

DLList.h

```
#include "Node.h"

template<typename T>
class DLList
{
public:
    DLList() : _head(nullptr) {}

    Node<T>* AddNode(T val)
    {
        Node<T>* m_prev = _head;

        Node<T>* m_node = new Node<T>(nullptr, m_prev, val);
        if (m_prev)
            m_prev->_next = m_node; 
        _head = m_node;
        return m_node;
    }

    Node<T>* First()
    {
        Node<T>* m_node = _head;
        while (m_node->Prev()) { m_node = m_node->Prev(); }
        return m_node;
    }

    Node<T>* Last()
    {
        return _head;
    }
private:
    Node<T>* _head;
};
```

Now I've did some tests with it and they're all fine, tests like:

```
#include "DLList.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    DLList<int> testList;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        testList.AddNode(i * 10);

    Node<int>* node = testList.First();
    do{
        cout << "value of node : " << node->Source() << endl;
    } while (node = node->Next());

    Node<int>* end = testList.Last();
    do{
        cout << "value of node : " << end->Source() << endl;
    } while (end = end->Prev());
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is that every time I have to declare a `Node` pointer to get the First or Last `Node` in the List I have to do it like this:
`Node<int>* end = testList.Last();` or `Node<int>* node = testList.First();`.
Since my list already knows the type `T` is there a possible implementation of `First()` and `Last()` where I can just do `Node* node = testList.First();` or `Node* end = testList.Last();` instead of having to supply the template arguments?

Comment: `Node` (or `Node*`) is not a valid type by itself. How would you like that to work???

Comment: @downvoters The question is quite obvious, care to explain why you're downvoting?

Comment: Did you try `auto` instead?

Comment: @Amit That was my question, is it possible to omit the template because my list has the type?

Comment: Did you try? Did it work? (I'm guessing no on both)

Comment: @Amit ofcourse I tried, the compiler can't figure out the template type so it errors out. That's why my question is, is there a way to not having to supply template argument _by re-implementing `First()` or `Last()`_?

Comment: 1. I didn't downvote (but I can see why others did). 2. You can implement `First` & `Last` however you want, but your question is what's "left in your hand" after the call. If you want to have something that links to the list, you must return something that links to the list. 3. You can use auto as (can't spell name, sorry :-) suggested, or you can typedef `Node<int>` somewhere. That's about it

Comment: @Amit Thanks, that explains it, I'll use `auto` then.

Comment: @JameyD No, your question wasn't really that _obvious_. Don't assume such, make it really clear. Usually you either provide a `typedef` or `using` type alias, if you wan't to omit the binding further, or use `auto`, as proposed in my answer.

Comment: time for a code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My first question is why would you want to expose the Node outside the class. Users of your class don't want to know how your class works they just want it to work. This is why the standard library `std::list` does not expose its internal structure, but does expose the values and `ITERATORS` to traverse the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Since my list already knows the type `T` is there a possible implementation of `First()` and `Last()` where I can just do `Node* node = testList.First();` or `Node* end = testList.Last();` ?"*

No, you can't, but you may use the `auto` keyword, to let the compiler deduce the actual type:

```
    auto node = testList.First();
 // ^^^^

    do{
        cout << "value of node : " << node->Source() << endl;
    } while (node = node->Next());
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not expose Node directly.

I would expose an `Iterator` type that is defined internally to the class (if that happens to be Node under the hood thats fine).

```
template<typename T>
class DLList
{
public:
    DLList() : _head(nullptr) {}

    typedef  Node<T>        iterator;
    typedef  Node<const T>  const_iterator;

    T&       First();      // would not expose a node here.
    T const& First() const;// I would return the first value in the list.

    iterator       begin();      // Iterator to first element.
    const_iterator begin() const;

    ....
```

Now you can use the auto trick to stop you specifying things too exactly.

```
int main()
{
    DLList<int>     data;
    // Add data.

    auto it = data.begin();
```